# Is it possible to backup installed software installers?

Tags: backup

Is it possible to download the installed software installers, and/or the Software Sources list? I'd like to make sure I have all that if some unfortunate event happened, and all I'd have to do is run them. Thanks. I'm still learning more and more about Ubuntu and it's really cool! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you downloaded them from the internet you can keep the .deb files for later installation.

IF you want to backup the sources list, just copy the file /etc/apt/sources.list like this:

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/sources.list.bak
cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d ~/sources.list.d
```

Comment: Soo-weeeeet! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gladen. 
Software installed from online repos "installs automatically" and comes along with its own libraries or may share libraries from other already installed softwares.
Most times we only watch the progress of the whole activity but dont really care/even know where it goes.

Backing up sorces is good and backing up "setups" is great